# Rollup function - Replace NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I seem to be having trouble with the final pieces of my SQL. 
When implementing the group by with roll up function within my SQL NULL appears. How can one modify NULL so that it is replaced with TOTAL within this aggregated SQL?

```
Current table returned
Name Activate Deactivate
Max      5       2
TAX     12       5
NULL    17       8

select 
    case 
    when (upper(m.email) like '%max.com') then 'MAX'
    when (upper(m.email) like '%tax.com') then 'TAX'
    else 'OTHER'
end Name, 
SUM(case when substring(convert(varchar(8),n.created_on,112),1,6) = '201209' then 1 else 0         end) 'Activated',
   SUM(case when substring(convert(varchar(8),m.LastLockoutDate,112),1,6)='201209' then 1 else 0              end) 'Deactivated'
           from membership.user_details d
          inner join membership.aspnet_membership m 
on m.userid = d.userid
        inner join membership.user_notes n 
         on n.userid = d.userid
        and n.CREATED_ON = (select min(created_on) 
                    from membership.user_notes 
                    where userid = n.userid
                        and note = 'received.')  
         where approved = 1
         group by case when (upper(m.email) like '%max.com') then 'MAX'
      when (upper(m.email) like '%tax.com') then 'TAX'
      else 'OTHER' end     
   with RollUp
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `ROLLUP` places a `null` in the totals row so if you want to replace that I would suggest taking your existing query and placing it in a subquery and then use a `CASE` on the `NAME` to replace the `null` to `Total`.

You code will be similar to this:

```
select 
  case when name is null then 'Total' else name end Name,
  sum(Activated) Activated,
  sum(Deactivated) Deactivated
from
(
  select 
    case 
      when (upper(m.email) like '%max.com') then 'MAX'
      when (upper(m.email) like '%tax.com') then 'TAX'
      else 'OTHER'
    end Name, 
  SUM(case when substring(convert(varchar(8),n.created_on,112),1,6) = '201209' then 1 else 0         end) 'Activated',
  SUM(case when substring(convert(varchar(8),m.LastLockoutDate,112),1,6)='201209' then 1 else 0              end) 'Deactivated'
  from membership.user_details d
  inner join membership.aspnet_membership m 
    on m.userid = d.userid
  inner join membership.user_notes n 
    on n.userid = d.userid
    and n.CREATED_ON = (select min(created_on) 
                        from membership.user_notes 
                        where userid = n.userid
                          and note = 'received.')  
  where approved = 1
  group by case when (upper(m.email) like '%max.com') then 'MAX'
        when (upper(m.email) like '%tax.com') then 'TAX'
        else 'OTHER' end     
) src
group by name with rollup
```

If you do not wrap your query in a subquery, then you can use something like this:

```
select
   case when 
     (case 
        when (upper(email) like '%max.com') then 'MAX'
        when (upper(email) like '%tax.com') then 'TAX'
        else 'OTHER'
      end) is null then 'Total'
      else case 
        when (upper(email) like '%max.com') then 'MAX'
        when (upper(email) like '%tax.com') then 'TAX'
        else 'OTHER'
      end end Name,
  SUM(case when substring(convert(varchar(8),n.created_on,112),1,6) = '201209' then 1 else 0 end) 'Activated',
  SUM(case when substring(convert(varchar(8),m.LastLockoutDate,112),1,6)='201209' then 1 else 0 end) 'Deactivated'
from membership.user_details d
inner join membership.aspnet_membership m 
  on m.userid = d.userid
inner join membership.user_notes n 
  on n.userid = d.userid
  and n.CREATED_ON = (select min(created_on) 
                     from membership.user_notes 
                     where userid = n.userid
                       and note = 'received.')  
where approved = 1
group by case when (upper(m.email) like '%max.com') then 'MAX'
        when (upper(m.email) like '%tax.com') then 'TAX'
        else 'OTHER' end with rollup
```

Comment: I actuallly when ahead and did case for the Total as you did above... took a while for me to think about it yesterday night. Thanks for your help bluefeet! Good day sir!

Comment: The only trick is `case when name is null then 'Total' else name end Name`

Comment: @guneysus I'm not exactly sure why you are down voting a correct answer. My answer includes the "trick" you are stating.

Comment: Because it is over-kill. Only `case when name is null then 'Total' else name end Name` is enough.

Comment: @guneysus: Not trying to discuss your voting reasons, just want to understand them. This answer would have been fine if it only had the first suggestion, but because it *additionally* includes the second part, *which actually works just as well but is overkill*, it's worth a downvote. Is that how you see it?

Comment: Sometimes, it is better to answer onyl the question. See the title of question. It only needs **Rollup function - Replace NULL**. No need to offer a complete query that's database is not known by every one. If the question was belong to Nortwind db, I wouldn't down vote.

Comment: @guneysus you've got the right to downvote any answer you want, I don't care about the vote. I tend to provide detailed solutions, in this case I provided two separate solutions to the same problem, letting the OP decide which version would work for them.

Comment: Just landed on this discussion, `case when name is null then 'Total' else name end Name` is also overkill, you can simply do `isnull(name, 'Total')` and you're done ^^

Answer (score 7):

Use this in place a straight Name reference:

`case when grouping(Name) then 'Total' else Name end as Name`

If only a single level of grouping is being used, a test for null suffices; hoowever the grouping(...) test allows different descriptions to be generated for each distinct grouping level.

Comment: When doing this the system retuns says that NAME is not a valid colum which it is not. It is only a temp column.

Comment: Got it. Add the suggested logic to your existing calculation, as the first case.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your `case` statement with an `isnull` function:

```
select 
    isnull
        (
        case 
            when (upper(m.email) like '%max.com') then 'MAX'
            when (upper(m.email) like '%tax.com') then 'TAX'
            else 'OTHER'
        end,
        'Total'
        ) Name, 
    SUM(case
            when substring(convert(varchar(8),n.created_on,112),1,6) = '201209'
            then 1
            else 0
        end) 'Activated',
    SUM(case
            when substring(convert(varchar(8),m.LastLockoutDate,112),1,6)='201209'
            then 1
            else 0
        end) 'Deactivated'
from membership.user_details d
    inner join membership.aspnet_membership m 
        on m.userid = d.userid
    inner join membership.user_notes n 
        on n.userid = d.userid
        and n.CREATED_ON =
            (
            select min(created_on) 
            from membership.user_notes 
            where userid = n.userid
                and note = 'received.'
            )  
where approved = 1
group by
    case
        when (upper(m.email) like '%max.com') then 'MAX'
        when (upper(m.email) like '%tax.com') then 'TAX'
        else 'OTHER'
    end     
with rollup
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of this part

> case 
>      when (upper(m.email) like '%max.com') then 'MAX'
>      when (upper(m.email) like '%tax.com') then 'TAX'
>      else 'OTHER'
>   end Name

simply use

> upper(REPLACE(COALESCE(m.email, 'other'), '.com', '')) as Name

no need to write a sub-query and complicate it further.

Answer (score 0):

In Snowflake, a [case](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/case.html) statement will solve this for you:

```sql
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN email IS NULL THEN 'Total'
        ELSE email
    END AS email,
    SUM(aggregate_field) AS total_thingy
FROM
    MY_TABLE
GROUP BY ROLLUP (email)
;
```