# horizontal and vertical totals in a pivot query in ms sql

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-ce, pivot

I am trying to do vertical and horizontal total of columns, please see the following query,
I was able to do vertical totals.

```
Select
  U_POD 'City',
  Sum([Customer TS Pending])  as    CTST ,
  sum([Pending])as P,
  sum([Pending SQ])as 'PSQ',
  sum([Tracking])as Tracking,
  SUM([Open])as Openn
from 
(
  Select T1.U_POD,T2.Name 
  from OSCL T0 
  inner join OCRD T1 
    on T0.Customer=T1.cardcode 
  inner join OSCS T2 
    on T2.statusID=T0.Status
)Service
Pivot
(
  count(Name)
  for Name IN ([Pending],[Pending SQ],[Tracking],[Open],[Customer TS Pending])
)pvt
group by rollup (pvt.U_POD)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `group by rollup` will give you the final row with the totals but if you are looking for a column with totals you can add a new computed column to your query:

```
 sum([Customer TS Pending] + [Pending] + [Pending SQ] + [Tracking] + [Open]) Total
```

This would make the full query:

```
Select
  U_POD 'City',
  Sum([Customer TS Pending])  as    CTST ,
  sum([Pending])as P,
  sum([Pending SQ])as 'PSQ',
  sum([Tracking])as Tracking,
  SUM([Open])as Openn,
  sum([Customer TS Pending] + [Pending] + [Pending SQ] + [Tracking] + [Open]) Total
from 
(
  Select T1.U_POD,T2.Name 
  from OSCL T0 
  inner join OCRD T1 
    on T0.Customer=T1.cardcode 
  inner join OSCS T2 
    on T2.statusID=T0.Status
)Service
Pivot
(
  count(Name)
  for Name IN ([Pending],[Pending SQ],[Tracking],[Open],[Customer TS Pending])
)pvt
group by rollup (pvt.U_POD)
```

Comment: just one question, how do I put 'Total' under the U_POD column for vertical Total, like I have 'Total' alias for Row totals.

Comment: @user2363530 You can use a case expression similar to this -- `case when U_POD is null then 'Total' else U_POD end City` -- here is a similar question/answer to that problem -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397298/rollup-function-replace-null