# Replace NULL in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

I have a table where there is NULL value and I want to replace the null with existing and matching value as per Col_2. **In below sample the NULL is getting generated from the roll up  group by rollup (col_1,col_2) function which I used..**

Below is the data :-

```
Col_1| Col_2| Col_3| Col_4| Col_5|Col_6
A    | B    |   B_1| 3    | 4    |  6
A    | B    |  B_1 | 6     | 8   |  6
```

Below is the output I need :-

```
Col_1| Col_2| Col_3| Col_4| Col_5|Col_6
A    | B    |   B_1| 3    | 4    |  6
A    | B    |  B_1 | 6     | 8   |  6
A    | B    |total B_1| 9  | 12  | 12
```

above is the sample data, so I want to replace null with value present in col_2.

for Ex :- NULL should be replaced with B and in last row it should be replace with X.

I have used

```
Select col_1,col_2,col_3,sum(col_4),sum(col_5),sum(col_6)
from table
group by rollup(col_1,col_2,col_3)
```

after using above query I am getting

Below is the table look like

```
  Col_1| Col_2| Col_3| Col_4| Col_5|Col_6
    A    | B    |   B_1| 3    | 4    |  6
    A    | B    |  B_1 | 6     | 8   |  6
    A    | NULL | total_B1| 9  | 12  | 12
```

Please help. Need to replace null with B.

Comment: You can "self-join" a table e.g. `SELECT * FROM tblA AS a INNER JOIN tblA AS b ON .....`. You need to figure out what column(s) to join it on.

Comment: I tried but not working on every rows..

Comment: Show us what you have tried and what did not work.

Comment: the null is getting generated by roll up function which I i am using

Comment: Descriptions are one thing but show us the actual desired results for the sample data; What if there were several rows of null values?

Comment: "null is getting generated by roll up function" - this is what it is supposed to do. `NULL` in the output means that it is the total for that group. I think you need to explain (and provide code) the whole situation, otherwise you will get "a right answer to the wrong question" situation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rollup function - Replace NULL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397298/rollup-function-replace-null)

Comment: no.. because he has only one column to handle

Comment: I think this answer looks promising https://stackoverflow.com/a/15397564/6305294 . You should be able to make it work for multiple columns

Answer (score -1):

```
Update yourTable set Col_2= (select top(1) Col_2 form yourTable a2 
where a2.Col_1=yourTable.Col_1 and a2.Col_3=yourTable.Col_3 and a2.Col_4=yourTable.Col_4 and a2.Col_5=yourTable.Col_5 and a2.Col_2 is not null)
where Col_2 is null and exists 
(select * form yourTable a3 
where a3.Col_1=yourTable.Col_1 and a3.Col_3=yourTable.Col_3 and a3.Col_4=yourTable.Col_4 and a3.Col_5=yourTable.Col_5 and a3.Col_2 is not null)
```